# Issues with series solution of the wave equation for a vibrating string

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, wave-equation

We are going to solve the classical wave equation
$$
c^2\partial^2_x y=\partial^2_t y.
$$
with boundary conditions $y(-\pi/2,t)=y(\pi/2,t)=0$ and initial condition $y(x,0)=f(x)=1-\frac{2|x|}{\pi}$.

The procedure is pretty standard, but I find the result quite unsatisfying. We have eigensolutions of the form
$$
A\cos nx \cos\frac{nt}{c}, n\text{ odd},\\
A\sin nx \cos\frac{nt}{c}, n\text{ even}.
$$
When I expand $f(x)$ into its Fourier series, I find that there is a constant term $1/2$, so we have something like
$$
f(x)=1/2+\sum (a_k \cos (2kx)+ b_k \sin(2kx)).
$$
The term $1/2$ corresponds to $n=0$ above, so at any time $t$, the term $1/2$ will remain there:
$$
y(x,t)=1/2+\sum (a_k \cos (2kx)\cos\frac{nk}{c}+ b_k \sin(2kx)\cos\frac{nk}{c}).
$$
I find this quite strange: how could we have a $1/2$ hanging out there? Although the string starts at a position above the $x$ axis, it should move to a position below it very soon, so how could it still have an $1/2$ above the y axis?

Did I do something incorrectly?

Comment: Being $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ but $0$ a constant term must appear.

Comment: @RafaBudríar Yes, but what's the physical interpretation?

Comment: Well, the 1/2 is for the initial conditions (further, all coefficients for $t=0$ are positive!). The system has to evolve and that coefficient has to cancel or even change sign in other times. I'd calculate the series for t half a period of the fundamental and for a complete period and see.